# callback needed when keyboard dismissed by sliding down animation instead of backpress or enter in android

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, keyboard

I am new to android  i am using setOnEditorActionListener to get callback when user clicks enter and backpress,,My issue is when user slides down the keyboard instead of backpress,,setOnEditorActionListener is not invoked,
is there any way to get callback by sliding down the keyboard by clicking dropdown beneath the keyboard Reference image attached [image]